# Redis Reactive sMembers and hMGet Flux

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-data-redis

I am new to reactive programming. I am trying to query the Redis in reactive fashion using Spring Webflux for smembers and then using that result need to query for hmget. The result of the sMembers query is Flux>, the hMGet is expecting
the second argument as Collection. I am not sure how to write this function in a right way. Can someone please help me in correcting this.

```
    return Flux.just(keys)
            .map(key -> { 
                 return reactiveClusterSetCommands.sMembers(ByteBuffer.wrap(key.getBytes())).flatMap(a ->  reactiveClusterHashCommands.hMGet(ByteBuffer.wrap(hash(key).getBytes()),a));
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Flux.collectList()` to collect `Flux<String>` into a `Mono<List<String>>` for set members and then use `flatMapMany` to call `HMGET` with a list of set members.

```
Flux.fromIterable(keys)
  .flatMap(key -> {
    ByteBuffer keyBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(key.getBytes());
    Mono<List<String>> setMembersMono = commands.sMembers(keyBytes).collectList();
    ByteBuffer hashKeyBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(hash(key).getBytes());
    setMembersMono.flatMapMany(setMembers -> commands.hMGet(hashKeyBytes, setMembers));
  });
```